# Why does this Indentation error form even though I am sure of spacing?

Tags: python, list, opencv, error-handling

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

X = []
Y = []

for c1 in cnts:
    # compute the center of the contour
    M = cv2.moments(c1)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    cv2.drawContours(imCrop, [c1], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.circle(imCrop, (cX, cY), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    X.append(cX)
    Y.append(cY)
```

I keep getting the following error and I have no clue. It does disappear when I get rid of the X.append(cX) and Y.append(cY), which I need to store (to record all centroid coordinates for multiple frames). I have checked many times for spacing/tabs problems but it is literally these list.append lines that cause the error. Any ideas?

```
    X.append(cX)
               ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: You've mixed tabs and spaces for indentation. Don't do that. This is what happens when you do.

Comment: "I have checked many times for spacing/tabs problems" - you didn't check well enough. Turn on "show whitespace" in your editor - it should help. There should also be a "convert indentation" tool somewhere.

Comment: If your editor is vim, run `:set expandtab` then `:retab` to change all your tabs to spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try using only spaces for your indentation to match indentation level

Just start from the beginning of the line and count 4 times :)

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and the link therein to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Questions caused by typos are explicitly off-topic, and should be closed, not answered.